# Salesforce connection with proxy not working

Tags: configuration, proxy, connection, salesforce, wildfly

I've a big problem getting the connection to Salesforce test environment (https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0).

I'm using Wildfly 10.0 as webserver and I've also tried to set the proxy in the standalone configuration.

This is my code:

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
config.setAuthEndpoint(endpoint);
config.setServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
config.setProxy(proxy_host, Integer.parseInt(proxy_port));
config.setProxyUsername(proxy_username);
config.setProxyPassword(proxy_password);

this.connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
```

In my working environment I've no problem with the connection because we have a proxy without authentication and it connects configuring just proxy_host and proxy_port.

In the customer environment, instead, I have the following exception despite I've configured all the proxy parameters correctly (including username and password):

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0

at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121)
at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(PartnerConnection.java:1426)
at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.<init>(PartnerConnection.java:406)
at com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector.newConnection(Connector.java:27)
.....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 authenticationrequired"
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2124)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:136)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:100)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:95)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:91)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:95)
```

The proxy configuration is working properly in telnet for istance.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!